# Extracting state-space from Atari games at specific frames and hard coding agents?

Tags: openai-gym

I am trying to extract the state space from Amidar in order to hard code an agent for some specific purposes. For example, I want the agent to go down whenever an enemy is 2 cells away or up until they hit a wall then go down again. However, I'm not quite sure how to extract the state space at a specific frame, or in general for that instance, and how to go about interpreting the output.

I have tried env.observation_space but that just returns the frame size (i.e: `Box(250,160,3)`). Anyone have an idea of how to go about doing this?

Thank you.